# How can i generate custom CIDetectorType?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, core-image, vision

I'm trying to find similarities in the images and align the images according to the position of the most similar object.

For example; I took 3 photos from different angles and there is always the same person's face in the photos. I choose one of the 3 photos as a reference. With CIDetector, I find the position of the faces in the photos and align them to the face in the reference photo. In this way, when I play the face-focused photos sequentially, I can create a focused boomerang effect.

My question is: As I find and align the faces in these 3 photos, can I align to objects such as cars, objects that I can specify apart from the default CIDetectorType values?

Actualy i am trying to make app like that app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkHdC.jpg

```
func findFace(){
        
        guard let middle = UIImage(named: "middle.jpg") else {
            return
        }
        
        guard let left = UIImage(named: "left.jpg") else {
            return
        }
        
        guard let right = UIImage(named: "right.jpg") else {
            return
        }
        
        
        guard let middleCIImage = CIImage.init(image: middle) else {return}
        guard let leftCIImage = CIImage.init(image: left) else {return}
        guard let rightCIImage = CIImage.init(image: right) else {return}
        
        let detector = CIDetector.init(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])
        
        let middleFeatures = detector?.features(in: middleCIImage)
        let leftFeature = detector?.features(in: leftCIImage)
        let rightFeature = detector?.features(in: rightCIImage)
    }
```

Comment: Last time I looked into it iOS did not support custom Core Image filters. I don’t know if that is still true, but as of about 5 years ago it was.

Comment: @DuncanC i can't connect your comment to my problem? Could you please describe?

Comment: I was thinking that a CIDetector is a form of Core Image (CI) filter. I might be be wrong about that, now that I think about it.

Comment: In any case, I don't think Core Image allows you to define your own CIDetector types. The docs only list 4 types of detectors, and say nothing about creating custom detectors.

Comment: Understand thanks you @DuncanC